# What are some chess books on openings which include computer analysis?

Tags: books

I once had a book on the sharp Wilkes-Barre variation of the Two Knights Defense written in the 1970s in which there were a few moves which were said to be clearly winning for one side in which a computer analysis of the position said otherwise. The situations were unusual, for example the last position in the analysis would have three threats in it and the conclusion would be that one side is clearly winning. Then the computer would find a move responding to all three threats and say that the other side has the advantage.

So my question is 'What are some books on chess openings that show how a computer rates the top move choices after analyzing each for a certain amount of time?'

Comment: Any chess book nowadays will be double-checked with computer analysis to avoid the type of erroneous conclusions you described. So you could probably say that practically all modern chess books will include computer analysis in some sense.

Comment: Traxler Counter-Attack is tactically one of the most complicated openings. So an analysis without an engine in this opening would contain errors very likely.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, The Wilkes-Barre is Traxler (correct me).

I once analyzed it quite deeply, and the only way white can hope for a win after 5. Nxf7 is 5...Bxf2+ 6. Kxf2 (6.Kf1 is also a tricky draw.) Nxe4+ 7. Ke3.

Or he can simply play 5. Bxf7+ and be a healthy pawn up.

You can do this analysis yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the newer endgame books will make use of at least the tablebases.

Nunn was the first to use computers to assist in analysis in writing one of his endgame books.

Comment: I don't recall which of Nunn's books it was. If anyone knows, please feel free to edit it in.